# How can I dynamically add configuration nodes in node-red

Tags: node.js, node-red

In my custom node's editor dialog, how can I add configuration nodes with js code, for example when I click a button, it will add a configuration node, and I can see it in the configuration sidebar of Node-RED editor? As in the node-red-dashboard, it will add the ui_base node when install the node-red-dashboard, how can it do this?
[node-red configuration sidebar screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4EAo.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After read the source code , I got the answer.
I made it possible by using the RED.nodes.add() api in my node's html file.